# How to access the routes in slim?

Tags: php, slim

I get a slim demo, but I am not familiar to that, I can see in the `routes.php` there are many `route` in the file.

Left is the `dir` structure, right is the `routes.php`.

This is `routes.php` code:

```
<?php
// Routes

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use LeanCloud\LeanObject;
use LeanCloud\LeanQuery;
use LeanCloud\LeanUser;
use LeanCloud\LeanACL;

$app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    if (!array_key_exists('status', $request->getQueryParams())) {
        $status = '0';
    } else {
        $status = $request->getQueryParams()['status'];
    }
    $user = LeanUser::getCurrentUser();

    $query = new LeanQuery('Todo');
    $query->limit(20)->addDescend('createdAt')->_include('owner');
    if ($status === '0') {
        $query->equalTo('done', false);
    } else {
        $query->equalTo('done', true);
    }
    $todos = $query->find();

    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'index.phtml', [
    'user' => $user,
    'status' => $status,
    'todos' => $todos,
    ]);
});

$app->post('/register', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    $user = new LeanUser();
    $user->setUsername($data['name']);
    $user->setPassword($data['password']);
    try {
      $user->signUp();
    } catch (\LeanCloud\CloudException $e) {
      return $this->renderer->render($response, 'register.phtml', ['error' => $e]);
    }
    return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', '/');
});

$app->get('/login2', function() {
    echo "login2";
});

//$app->get('/login3', );
```

My requirment is easy, how can I call the `/login2` or `/register` functions in the `broswer` such as `google` or `firefox` ?

eg:

`localhost/index.php/register`  ? (I test, get nothing)

If you need more infomation, please commit below the question.

**My test**

1)localhost/register

2)localhost/login2

**EDIT: I know how to access the route**

after the remind, in broswer , I use `localhost/public/index.php`, I access the `/` route:

Comment: Shoudnt be localhost/register?

Comment: @Mihai I have edited my question, there has my test in `firefox`.

Comment: I\`m guessing here but you need a get function like the one which request the base `/` so clone that function but with /register` $app->get..`

Comment: @Mihai I m confused，could not understand less, could you give a example? and you see my `/login2` I write to test, there is no need params ? I also test that. I m a iOSer, not so similiar to `php`.

Comment: it is ``localhost/public/login2``

Comment: @jmattheis it is not show.bro.i test that.

Comment: Does the first route work properly? What URL do you use to access the first route? (by 'the first route' i mean `$app->get('/', ... )` route in the beginning of your `routes.php` file)

Comment: @krlv tell the truth, I don't know how to call the `$app->get('/', ... )` route use `chrome`.

Comment: try `localhost` and `localhost/index.php/`

Comment: Oh, In my root `dir`, there is a `index.php` with nothing except a echo `xx`; should I remove it? if not remove, the broswer is request the root `dir` index.php

Comment: As I can see from screenshot of your project, the web server's root dir is `slim-todo-demo-master/public`. Check `public/index.php` file - it should have code to initialize Slim framework, at least something like `$app->run();` in the end of a file.

Comment: @krlv great, i access , you see my `edit`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129145/discussion-between-aircraft-and-krlv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can access `/login2` route with following URL:
`localhost/public/index.php/login2`